# Generate the permutation of the first N numbers in IA-32 Assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, permutation

I have to create an asm block in IA-32 assembly with Visual Studio.
I have tried to use the generation in lexicographical order but am now stuck as I don't know how to continue.
I cannot add variables and I cannot change the part written in C. I can only create the asm block.

As a guide I used the wikipedia page which says:

> The following algorithm generates the next permutation
> lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given
> permutation in-place.
>
> 1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index
>    exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
> 2. Find the largest
>    index l greater than k such that a[k] < a[l].
> 3. Swap the value of a[k]
>    with that of a[l].
> 4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and
>    including the final element a[n].
>
> For example, given the sequence [1,
> 2, 3, 4] (which is in increasing order), and given that the index is
> zero-based, the steps are as follows:
>
> 1. Index k = 2, because 3 is placed at an index that satisfies condition
>    of being the largest index that is still less than a[k + 1] which is
>    4
> 2. Index l = 3, because 4 is the only value in the sequence that is greater than 3 in order to satisfy the condition a[k] < a[l].
> 3. The
>    values of a[2] and a[3] are swapped to form the new sequence
>    [1,2,4,3].
> 4. The sequence after k-index a[2] to the final element is
>    reversed. Because only one value lies after this index (the 3), the
>    sequence remains unchanged in this instance. Thus the lexicographic
>    successor of the initial state is permuted: [1,2,4,3].
>
> Following this
> algorithm, the next lexicographic permutation will be [1,3,2,4], and
> the 24th permutation will be [4,3,2,1] at which point a[k] < a[k + 1]
> does not exist, indicating that this is the last permutation.

```c
/********************************************************************************
Descrizione: Generate all permutations of the first N natural numbers.
             The permutations generated must be inserted within a single
             array of integers. For example, if N = 3, the array must contain:
            {1,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,2,1}.

 ********************************************************************************/


#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
// Variabiles
int N=4;    // number of integers (<=6)
int Perm[4326]; // array permutations: size is sufficient for N <= 6
int Num = 0;    // At the end it must contain the number of permutations generated

//asm block
    __asm 
    {
        MOV EAX, N
        XOR EBX, EBX    //K+1
        MOV ECX, 1      //Counter K
        MOV EDX, N      //L
        XOR ESI, ESI    //Permutation Counter
        XOR EDI, EDI    

Inizializzazione :      //Set the first N numbers of the array in order
        MOV Perm[ECX*4-4], ECX
        INC ECX
        CMP ECX, EAX
        JLE Inizializzazione
        INC ESI
        
MakeOffset:             //Use MUL to set the offset index in EDI
        MOV EAX, 1
        MUL ESI
        MOV EDI, EAX
        
PermStore:
        INC EDI
        MOV ECX, Perm[EDI*4-4] //a[K+1]
        DEC EDI
        MOV EBX, Perm[EDI*4-4] //a[K]
        CMP EBX, ECX
        JL Swap
        DEC EDI
        JNS PermStore
        DEC EAX
        JS End
        MOV EDI, EAX
        DEC EDI
        JMP PermStore

Swap:
        DEC EDX
        MOV ECX, Perm[EDX*4-4] //a[L]
        CMP ECX, EBX
        JG Greater

Greater:
        //I have to use ECX (which is L) and EBX (a[k]), I have to use EDI for K and EAX for the offset moltiplications of L
        //Now I take a[k] and store it in position L and then I store the one which was in L in position K

Reverse:    //Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n]

End:

    }

// Stampa su video
    {
        int i,j,k;
        printf("Permutazioni dei primi %d numeri naturali\n",N);
        for (i=k=0;i<Num;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                printf("%3d",Perm[k++]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MSVC uses EBP to address locals, so if you need more space than you have registers, you could make some stack space for it (push or `sub esp, xx`) and reference it relative to ESP.  e.g.  something you don't use very often, like an outer-loop variable.  That's a weird way to use inline asm, but you *could*.  However, given the 6 integer registers you have to play with (not including ESP and EBP), that may be enough.

Comment: So what's your actual question?  You found an algorithm and you have part of an implementation.  If you're looking for code to reverse an array, there are several duplicate of that on SO.  (given pointers or indices of the ends of your range, load / store opposite, walk pointers inward while (i < j), i.e. until they meet or cross.